# Is TBB pre-Enabled in Opencv-2.4.5?

Tags: c++, c, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have posted a question in Opencv answers group regarding the performance of TBB. An this is the [link](http://answers.opencv.org/question/14226/opencv-with-both-tbb-and-ipp/?answer=14231#post-id-14231).

The answer in this link states as below.

> Probably you used the 2.4.5 library with and without TBB to compare,
>   however, since OpenCV 2.4.3 multithreaded support functionality has
>   been included in the source code, not needing to build openCV with the
>   TBB support anymore. It is done automatically where necessary and the
>   included dll's are contained in the source where needed.

But I faced performance chage in Hog descriptor. That is I used peopledetect.cpp from samples and compiled with both TBB and without TBB in opencv2.4.5. I can see the Opencv2.4.5 compiled with TBB performs 2x speed where as Opencv2.4.5 without TBB performs very slow.

Can some one please conform the below points, as I couldnt find any belivable sources.

1) From opencv2.4.3 dont we need to make the opencv rebuild with TBB ON?

Answer (score 3):

The prebuild binaries are compiled with the Visual Studio Concurrency framework since 2.4.3. However, not every algorithm uses the "new" parallel interface, where you can switch from Concurrency to IPP to TBB. Before, it was afaik hardcoded to use either TBB or nothing.
So the problem is that not every algorithm has been converted to the new parallel way, thus you can get speedups using TBB in some ways. (IIRC one example is the BruteForceMatcher, which uses only one core with the prebuild libs)